# Chart JS: is possible mix Scatter and bar chart in Chart JS?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, histogram

[image]

I have this plot in matplotlib python, this is a histogram and some specifics functions. I'm trying the same plot with ChartJS using bar/line mixed chart. The problem is that the the x-axis points have to be the same for both graphs and the form of the function is not achieved. Is this plot possible in Chart JS. If not, what libraries can I use?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible by using a second x axis with the same labels but the offset and display set to false:

```js
const labels = ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"];

const options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels,
    datasets: [{
        type: 'line',
        xAxisID: 'x2',
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'orange',
        backgroundColor: 'orange'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink',
        backgroundColor: 'pink'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {},
      x2: {
        labels,
        offset: false,
        display: false
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: ok. that's perfect, only a question. Is possible that the second x-axis let be different in size and values. For example, I want to make that the axis of bar plot [1,2,3,4,5] and the axis of the scatter/line [0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5].

Comment: yeah just provide a different labels array or use object format